# Redmine: is there a way to set the order of custom fields?

Tags: project-management, redmine

Is there a way to set the order of custom fields in a RedMine tracker?

For example, suppose we have tracker `Foo` with two custom fields, `bar` and `baz`. The `baz` field was created after `bar`, so it follows it in the issue as it is rendered for the user. Is there a way to make `baz` *precede* `bar` instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you can order the fields with the sort arrows at their right side. This order will be the same for all trackers.

Comment: there is also a nice, but yet unimplemented, request so one could define a **custom layout** (and not the 2-column standard one): http://www.redmine.org/issues/8417